# Is there a way to allow only the branch creator to push on it in Github?

Tags: github

- I have a Github organization.
- I created a repository and a team to work on it.
- I want to restrict push to any branch to it's creator by the default.
- So that no one can push to someone's else branch.
- Is there any method to do that other than adding rule for every branch manually?

I tried to add rules manually, but it's time consuming cause there are many people joining the team.

**Update:**

- I went to my organization -> teams.
- Selected the team, went to members, selected a member.
- Clicked on "manage access" next to one repository, clicked "edit".
- Set "Base permissions" to "Write".
- Set "Repository creation" to "Disabled".
- Everything else is left unchecked.

Comment: Can't you use a bash script, or something analogous, to automate the creation of the rules?

Comment: Can you illustrate please?

Comment: Show us the rules you create by hand for each user, and I'll show you how to make bash do it. (Please add your code by **editing your question**, not in a comment --and no images please.)

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on whether or not this is a good idea.
Suffice to say I was annoyed once leading me to create the following ***update*** hook to apply to the canonical repo (**note however that Github does not allow custom update hooks so you're out of luck there**):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import check_output


branch = sys.argv[1]
old_commit = sys.argv[2]
new_commit = sys.argv[3]
zero = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
branch_pattern = 'feature/.+'


def get_author(commit):
    return str(check_output(['git', '--no-pager', 'show', '-s', "--format='%an'", commit]).strip(), 'utf-8')


def allow(message=None):
    if message:
        print(message)
    exit(0)


def deny(message=None):
    if message:
        print(message)
    exit(1)


# if this isn't a feature branch bail
if not re.match(branch_pattern, branch):
    allow()

# if the update is a delete bail
if new_commit == zero:
    allow("update: deleting branch '%s': OK" % branch)

# if this is the first commit on the branch bail
if old_commit == zero:
    allow("update: creating branch '%s': OK" % branch)

branch_log = Path('.git', 'logs', 'refs', 'heads').joinpath(*branch.split(os.path.sep))
with open(branch_log, 'r') as log:
    first_commit = log.readline(81).split(sep=' ', maxsplit=1)[1]

branch_author = get_author(first_commit)
new_commit_author = get_author(new_commit)

print("update: branch = '%s'; branch author = %s; commit author = %s" % (branch, branch_author, new_commit_author))

if new_commit_author == branch_author:
    allow("update: commit author == branch author: OK")
else:
    deny(
        "update: branch author != commit author: REJECTED\n"
        "update: create a branch for your changes from the tip of %s and request a pull instead"
        % branch
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Organization owners and people with admin permissions for organization-owned repositories can enforce branch restrictions so that only certain users or teams are able to push to a protected branch.

For more info, [see](https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions) here

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the problem. The OP knows about protected branches, and is asking if there is a way to prevent pushes to a branch by all but the *_creator_* of that branch on the github repo. I suspect he is trying to address a scenario such as the following: - dev creates new feature branch; works on story and pushes changes to github, creating remote tracked branch; does some more work and goes to push it only to have the push rejected because someone else clobbered his feature branch - he is trying to stop other dogs pissing on his newly planted trees